# Error while doing phone number verification using twilio in swift

Tags: swift, twilio, alamofire

I want to verify phone number by getting one time password. But I am getting some error. Please look into the code bellow and help me to resolve it. I am using Twilio for mobile verification. And Alamofire for API request. But the error I am getting like:-

```
Authentication Error - No credentials provided.
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format
```

**My code is:-**

**Here is my model class: -**

```
...struct SendVerificationCode: Codable {
let status: String?
let payee: String?
let dateUpdated: Date?
let sendCodeAttempts: [SendCodeAttempt]?
let accountSid, to: String?
let amount: Int?
let valid: Bool?
let lookup: Lookup?
let url: String?
let sid: String?
let dateCreated: Date?
let serviceSid, channel: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case status, payee
    case dateUpdated = "date_updated"
    case sendCodeAttempts = "send_code_attempts"
    case accountSid = "account_sid"
    case to, amount, valid, lookup, url, sid
    case dateCreated = "date_created"
    case serviceSid = "service_sid"
    case channel
}
}


struct Lookup: Codable {
let carrier: Carrier?
}


struct Carrier: Codable {
let mobileCountryCode, type: String?
let errorCode: String?
let mobileNetworkCode, name: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case mobileCountryCode = "mobile_country_code"
    case type
    case errorCode = "error_code"
    case mobileNetworkCode = "mobile_network_code"
    case name
}
}


 struct SendCodeAttempt: Codable {
let channel, time: String?
}...
```

**Api Request:-**

```
...func sendcode(mobileWithCode: String, completion: @escaping sendTwillioVerificationCodeCompletion) {

    let url = URL(string: SEND_TWILIO_VERIFICATION_CODE)
   var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
   urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
   urlRequest.addValue(userNameData, forHTTPHeaderField: "Username")
    urlRequest.addValue(PasswordData, forHTTPHeaderField: "Password")
    urlRequest.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


   Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { (response) in
       if let error = response.result.error {
           debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
           completion(nil)
           return
       }

       guard let data = response.data else { return completion(nil)}

       Common.sharedInstance().printRequestOutput(data: data)

       let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
       do {
           let clear = try jsonDecoder.decode(SendVerificationCode.self, from: data)
           completion(clear)
       } catch {
           debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
           completion(nil)
       }
   }
}...
```

**But i am getting error:-**

```
   {"code": 20003, "detail": "Your AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect.", "message": "Authentication Error - No credentials provided", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003", "status": 401}
   "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."
```

**Also i have tried the following code:-**

```
import Foundation
semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

let parameters = "To=+919778882332&Channel=sms"
let postData =  parameters.data(using: .utf8)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:  myUrl)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue(requestData, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = postData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
guard let data = data else {
print(String(describing: error))
return
}
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
semaphore.signal()
}

task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
```

**But i am getting error like**

```
"Invalid parameter"
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks as though your code is trying to call the Twilio API directly from the device and that you weren't setting your Account SID or Auth Token in that.

The issue here is that you should not store or access your auth token from within your application. That would make your account sid and auth token vulnerable to be stolen and then used to abuse your account.

Instead, you should create a server side application that talks to the Twilio API and then call that from your application.

As Jamil pointed out, there is a blog post you can follow on [performing phone verification in iOS with Twilio Verify and Swift](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/phone-verification-in-ios-with-twilio-verify-and-swift.html) and I recommend you go through that. It includes [an example server side application to call the Twilio Verify API](https://github.com/robinske/verify-server) built in Python, but you could build your own too.

Comment: Hi Philnash, thanks for your responce. is it compulsory to deploy it into heroku or we can use our server.When i am using our server it is showing the error like :- "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Comment: It is not compulsory to deploy it to heroku no, you can deploy anywhere you are comfortable with. It's also not compulsory to use the Python example, you can also build your own. When you say you are getting an error, what do you mean? Have you configured and started the application properly? Can you make a request to it from a browser/Postman/curl?

Comment: Yes I postman it is working fine.but when I am copy and pasting the same code , I am getting the error like - invalid parameter.

Comment: I need some more information here. Are you using the Python example? What is the code you are using to make a request to that server? What do you mean when you copy and paste the code? Perhaps you can edit your question with what you are doing now and the code you are using? Let me know and I'll take a look.

Comment: let parameters = "To=+919887766554&Channel=sms" let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8) var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity) request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") request.addValue(userData, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") request.httpMethod = "POST" request.httpBody = postData let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in guard let data = data else { return } } task.resume()

Comment: Can you please update your question. It's impossible to read code in Stack Overflow comments.

Comment: Yes i have edited my question and added the code there.

Comment: You have `request.addValue(requestData, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")` in your code, but `requestData` is never defined. Is that your invalid parameter? The latest code you shared looks like it might run in an Xcode playground rather than in an app too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Config", ofType: "plist")
    static let config = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
    private static let baseURLString = config!["serverUrl"] as! String

    @IBOutlet var countryCodeField: UITextField! = UITextField()
    @IBOutlet var phoneNumberField: UITextField! = UITextField()
    @IBAction func sendVerification() {
        if let phoneNumber = phoneNumberField.text,
            let countryCode = countryCodeField.text {
            ViewController.sendVerificationCode(countryCode, phoneNumber)
        }
    }

    static func sendVerificationCode(_ countryCode: String, _ phoneNumber: String) {

        let parameters = [
            "via": "sms",
            "country_code": countryCode,
            "phone_number": phoneNumber
        ]

        let path = "start"
        let method = "POST"

        let urlPath = "\(baseURLString)/\(path)"
        var components = URLComponents(string: urlPath)!

        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            let item = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
            queryItems.append(item)
        }

        components.queryItems = queryItems

        let url = components.url!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = method

        let session: URLSession = {
            let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            return URLSession(configuration: config)
        }()

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let jsonSerialized = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]

                    print(jsonSerialized!)
                }  catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

For more please check this link: [Link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/07/phone-verification-in-ios-with-twilio-verify-and-swift.html).

Comment: Hi jamil, i tried the same code. why i am getting error like "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Comment: let parameters = "To=+919887766554&Channel=sms"
let postData =  parameters.data(using: .utf8)
var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue(userData, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = postData
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
  guard let data = data else {
    return
  }
}
task.resume()

Comment: Also tried the above code. it is showing the error like: -                                                     {"code": 60200, "message": "Invalid parameter: To", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200", "status": 400}

Comment: @TapanRaut Just pull this project and run: https://github.com/robinske/phone-verification-swift
Hope it will help you a bit.